# Get lengths of multiple vector subsets defined by a vector of subset parameters

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector `x` of `n` elements.

Now I want to get multiple subsets of this vector of the scheme `s = subset(x, x<=p)` where `p` will hold several values, given through a vector.

In the end I would like to have the lengths of these subsets stored in a vector according to the vector containing the values for `p`.

Can you help me doing this without loops etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another, less memory-demanding, solution:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- rnorm(20) 
p <- c(-1, 0, 1)
## sapply(p, function(pi) sum(x <= pi))
[1] 1 5 8
```

A benchmark:

```
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(42)
x <- rnorm(20000)
p <- rnorm(100)
microbenchmark(setNames(colSums(outer(x, p, "<=")), p), sapply(p, function(pi) sum(x <= pi)))
## Unit: milliseconds
##                                     expr      min       lq  median       uq      max neval
##  setNames(colSums(outer(x, p, "<=")), p) 29.33870 87.21804 88.5226 89.94144 94.34427   100
##     sapply(p, function(pi) sum(x <= pi)) 21.52853 22.23344 22.2959 22.46226 26.13650   100
```

Comment: But this is not "without loops" (which I take to mean that they only want C-level loops).

Comment: But `sapply` uses `lapply` and `lapply` calls `.Internal(lapply(X, FUN))` - it's a "C-level loop"

Comment: I don't really agree. After all, `for` is also implemented in C. In both cases your are passing an R expression/function to a looping function.

Comment: Anyway, playing with `outer` is a little bit more expensive (especially for large p and x).. I've added some benchmarks above

Answer (score 1):

```
set.seed(42)
x <- rnorm(20) 
p <- c(-1, 0, 1)

setNames(colSums(outer(x, p, "<=")), p)
#-1  0  1 
# 3 10 14
```

Explanation:

Using `<=` in `outer` tests each element of `x` against each element of `p`. Calculating the colwise sums gives the number of `TRUE` values for each `p` value. At last, we use the `p` values as names.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As my data vector is not big, I don't really care about speed, so this one is just as good.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, let's do it with Rcpp. Here I sort the input first and then take advantage of that:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector countsmaller(NumericVector x, const NumericVector p) {
  x=x.sort();
  NumericVector sorted = clone(p).sort();
  IntegerVector order=match(p, sorted);
  int count = 0;
  double prob=sorted(0);
  int i=0;
   for(int j = 0; j < x.size(); ++j) {
      if (x(j) <= prob) 
      {
        count++;
      } 
      else 
      {
        if (i < sorted.size()-1)
        {
          sorted(i)=count;
          i++;
          prob=sorted(i);  
          if (x(j) <= prob) count++; else j--;
        }
      }
    }
    sorted(sorted.size()-1) = count;
   return sorted[order-1];
}
```

Is it faster?

```
set.seed(42)
x <- rnorm(20000)
p <- rnorm(100)

all.equal(countsmaller(x, p), 
          sapply(p, function(pi) sum(x <= pi)))
#TRUE

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(colSums(outer(x, p, "<=")), 
sapply(p, function(pi) sum(x <= pi)),
countsmaller(x, p)
)

# Unit: milliseconds
#                                 expr       min        lq    median        uq        max neval
#           colSums(outer(x, p, "<=")) 22.354525 64.833602 65.343129 66.161082 149.428049   100
# sapply(p, function(pi) sum(x <= pi)) 12.922805 13.344871 14.444304 15.009727  58.607176   100
#                   countsmaller(x, p)  1.650383  1.703044  1.730453  1.754937   2.222273   100
```